# How does Django handle the incrementation of the AutoField Primary Key?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

In a **Django** project with **postgresql**, I once inserted en entry in the db, and one day. Someone else who has access to it, has manually added 36 other rows in the db with **pgadmin4**. When I want to add new row with the Django project, I got `IntegrityError` obviously, because **Django** tries to add 1 to the last entry id added by the Django project (This is what I think it is trying to do). Here is the traceback:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "register_catalog_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.
```

How to tell Django that the last entry id is 36 (the last value manually added with pgadmin4)?

I also tried to have the id field in Django Admin so I could edit it, but it did not show up.

```
class RegisterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    list_display_links = ['id',]
    list_display = ('id',)
```

Do I need to remove the primary key handled by **Django**, and define an *IntegerField* as primary key?

```
register_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

to

```
register_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

Comment: This has to be fixed in the database. You have to reset the sequence, usually with something like `ALTER SEQUENCE <table>_id_seq RESTART WITH <next_id>`. Where you have to replace the values in `<>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`ALTER SEQUENCE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-altersequence.html) command

```
ALTER SEQUENCE <table_name>_id_seq RESTART WITH 37
```

Ex: `ALTER SEQUENCE myapp_register_id_seq RESTART WITH 37`